# Сферы использования QML, Для чего он используется в разработке? Отличия от Qt?

Tags: qt, qml

Знакомлюсь с `QML`, в интернете из описания не нашел ничего кроме

> QML - это декларативный язык, используемый для разметки пользовательского интерфейса приложения. Он разбивает пользовательский интерфейс на более мелкие элементы, которые могут быть объединены в компоненты. QML описывает внешний вид и поведение этих элементов пользовательского интерфейса. Такая разметка может быть дополнена кодом JavaScript для обеспечения  более сложной логики UI. С этой точки зрения, QML следует шаблону HTML-JavaScript, но QML разработан с нуля и предназначен для разметки  пользовательских интерфейсов, а не текстовых документов. 
>   В общем случае QML представляет собой иерархию элементов. Дочерние элементы наследуют систему координат от родителя.

Или чего-то подобного.

Где можно найти подробное описание? Для чего, например, `QML` используется при разработке мобильных приложений, структуру проекта на `QML`, Почему в проектах нельзя обойтись обычным `Qt`?

В общем подробное введение в `QML`, чтобы разобраться, какие задачи с помощью него можно решить.

Во всех источниках сразу учат писать на нем код, вводной части практически нет, так как `QML` дают в перемешку с `Qt`. Может кто рассказать, зачем его вообще придумали и его плюсы по сравнению с `Qt`?

Comment: Вы путаете мягкое с тёплым. Qt - это библиотека графического интерфейса, а QML - это язык описания интерфейсов для этой библиотеки.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Но создать интерфейс можно и с помощью QGraphicsView, Scene, Item разве нет?

Comment: Можно, но писать придётся больше и сложнее.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev То есть QML  Был  создан просто для облегчения разработки UI в библиотеке предназначенной для разработки UI? Как то не вяжется, новую ветку Qt можно было выпустить не называть ее QML, простите, конечно, но я правда хочу понять цель создания QML, как отдельного, пусть и неразрывно связанного с Qt языка

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, ничего он не путает, QML это изобретение Nokia, на котором она благополучно обанкротилась. Из наличия больших понтов нокиа решила не идти по пути Apple, то есть приспособить существующий интерфейс под touchscreen, а начала изобретать и сейчас мы имеем по факту два фреймворка в одном Qt

Comment: @PavelGridin А статей на эту тему не сохранилось?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, эта история более-менее полно описана в википедии в статье MeeGo. Только тогда QML ещё назывался QtMobility

Comment: Зачем придумали не знаю. По поводу плюсов - UI на Qml можно набросать быстрее, он (наверное) более понятет всяким веб девелоперам (потому что там есть JS). Ещё он позволяет отделить логику приложения (бизнес-логику, или как там это называется) от собственно UI в каком-то смысле даже удобнее, чем это можно сделать с помощью стандартных виджетов Qt.